# Debian 9.7 - Add additional IP address. Different methods - advatages and disadvantages

Tags: ip

I have dedicated server from some well known hoster and I bought new ip. I try to figured out what are advatages and disdvatages two methods of finish this task on debian 9.7

1) first method - which I found in hoster manual is to add two lines to interface

```
up ip addr add [new ip]/32 dev [interface]
down ip addr del [new ip]/32 dev [interface]
```

2) second method I found on the web is to add

```
auto [NIC]:[n]
iface [NIC]:[n] inet static
address [ip.add.rr.ss]
gateway [gw.ip.ad.rs]
netmask [ne.tm.as.kk]
```

In new system like debian 9.7 I read that there is not nesesery to adding subinterface ":[n]" just the same name of interface

But is there any advatages or disadvanteges between this two methods?

Answer (score 0):

First method will assign address for interfaces temporary.
Second will assign permanently. 
That is the difference.

Comment: both method I could add to network config file and I thought that both are permanent only shell comannd "ip addr add x.y.z.v/32 dev eth0" is temporary, isn't it? Both method are desribe in debian wiki as iprout2 method: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface